# Can Shor's algorithm factor multi-prime numbers?

Tags: rsa, factoring, quantum-cryptanalysis, shors-algorithm

I know that [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) can factor semi-primes ($N = p \times q \space, \{p, \space q \in \Bbb{P} \space \vert \space p, \space q \gt 0 \} $).

Assuming that all prime numbers are so large that it's infeasible to compute with any known classical algorithm, can Shor's algorithm also factor multi-primes, meaning where $N$ has more than two prime-factors?

Comment: Also, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3932/54184.

Comment: Seems 1024-Bit RSA is protected from implementations of Shor's algorithm for quite a long time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can. Quoting the [document of DJB: "Post-quantum RSA" by
Daniel J. Bernstein, Nadia Heninger, Paul Lou and Luke Valenta](https://cr.yp.to/papers/pqrsa-20170419.pdf), which [forest has linked to](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68971/can-shors-algorithm-factor-multi-prime-numbers#comment153361_68971):

> If $n$ is a product of more primes, say $k \ge 3$ primes, then the same speedup
>   becomes even more effective, using $k$ exponentiations with ($1/k$)-size exponents
>   and ($1/k$)-size moduli. Prime generation also becomes much easier since the
>   primes are smaller. Of course, if primes are too small then the attacker can find
>   them using the ring algorithms discussed in the previous section|specifically
>   EECM before quantum computers, and GEECM after quantum computers.

As we don't know how to factor multi-prime RSA, with e.g. 3 exponents of 1024 bits using classical computing, we can surmise that Shor can factor multi-primes that would be out of reach otherwise.

The article then goes on to exploring how many primes and how large a modulus size would be sufficient to ward off attacks by a full quantum computer, and comes out at 1-terabyte key, 4096-bit primes and $2^{31}$ multiplications to create the modulus.

Probably we should look at other alternatives before turning to RSA for Post Quantum Cryptography, another one of the conclusions of the paper.

Comment: Is there an estimation of how long an exchange of a secret between two parties would take with a key of size 1 terabyte?

Comment: Yes, see chapter 4 of the paper: "Concrete parameters and initial implementation" - although the full 1 TB has N/A (actually, it's not even present in the table as previous sizes already have N/A), so you would have to extrapolate (to "not funny anymore").

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It might be worth noting that those benchmarks were done on a supercomputing cluster, not an average home computer. It would take _far_ longer to even multiply $2^{31}$ integers on a PC.

Answer (score 6):

Shor's algorithm finds the prime factors of any integer, regardless of the number of primes. This is explained in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm#Procedure) which describes how the algorithm takes an odd integer and finds another integer which divides it. If the composite number is not a semiprime, then you just run Shor's algorithm on the result again to get another integer which divides it. Repeat until only primes remain.

Answer (score 6):

- Shor's algorithm works by using quantum magic to compute a period of $f\colon x \mapsto a^x \bmod n$ for random $a$; if it gives $2t$ so that $a^{2t} \equiv 1 \pmod n$, and if $a^t \not\equiv -1 \pmod n$, then $\gcd(a^t \pm 1, n)$ is a nontrivial factor of $n$.  (Otherwise, repeat with another $a$.)  If $n = p q r$ and $\gcd(a^t \pm 1, n) = p$, then you can lather, rinse, and repeat for $n' = n/p = q r$.

  The cost is dominated by $(\lg n)^{2 + o(1)}$ qubit operations to compute $f$—that is, it is quadratic in the size of the *modulus* $n$.

Post-quantum RSA chooses $n$ so large that this quadratic gap is infeasible for an attacker (of course, merely using pqRSA is also only barely feasible as a joke for well-funded users), but that's not the only avenue for attack:

- If a prime factor is bounded by $y$, then $\gcd(f(n, u), n)$ may be a nontrivial factor of $n$, where $f(n, u)$ is a product of many distinct primes below $y$ modulo $n$, randomized by $u$—*e.g.*, trial division, Pollard's $\rho$, ECM, *etc.*  If $n = p q r$ and you find $u$ so that $\gcd(f(n, u), n) = p$, then you can lather, rinse, and repeat for $n' = n/p = q r$.

  Grover's algorithm finds a preimage of 0 under $u \mapsto [\gcd(n, f(n, u)) = 1]$ in the time for about $\sqrt{y}$ quantum evaluations of $f$.  For the best $f$, ECM, where $u$ is a random curve choice, the combined cost of Grover-ECM is $L^{1 + o(1)}$ where $L = e^{\sqrt{\log y \log \log y}}$—that is, it is superpolynomial but subexponential in the size of the *factors* $p$, $q$, and $r$.

Consequently, post-quantum RSA chooses $p$, $q$, $r$, and millions of other factors, to be 4096 bits apiece so that this superpolynomial/subexponential gap is infeasible for an attacker while the user can still compute arithmetic modulo $p$, $q$, $r$, and the other factors individually at reasonable cost.

Comment: Actually, in Shor's algorithm, $a$ is not random; instead, it's the value that the attacker picks.

Comment: @poncho What happens if the attacker picks an element of small order?  The standard approach, as far as I know, is to choose $a$ at random (maybe from a distribution that favors small values) and confirm it neither shares factors with $n$ nor has small order first, classically; and then use it in a QFT circuit.  Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're not (except that there really isn't any 'standard approach', as no one can actually do it yet); if $a$ is selected at random, the probability that it has tiny order is actually neglectable (and a nontiny order of an element can be used to factor, even if $t$ is odd or if $a^{t/2}$ happens to be -1).